# how to improve range search in BST by adding additional information?

Tags: c, data-structures

I was required to improve range Search function in BST's Big-O by adding additional information  to tree nodes.
that improvement increases Big-O to O(h), h is height and
additional information should be added and subtracted by inserting and deleting nodes.
therefore, We needs to modify BST's insert and delete algorithm.

under, there are rangeSearch,Insert,Delete function's declaration and function description.

1. range search function is
   **int rangeSearch(Tree T,int a,int b)**
   that counts the number between a and b in tree.
2. Insert function is
   **Node insert(Node n,Element e)**
   that inserts Element e in Node n.
3. Delete function is
   **Node Delete(Node n,Element e)**
   that deletes Node n which has element e.

finally, that I really hope to be given answer is **what should be added in tree node.**
and if you give me the answer through C programming, I am really glad !!
please give me clear answer !!
and if you need more information, please let me know what information you want.

Comment: Sounds like a balance factor as used in [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) trees would be useful.

Comment: oh!! good approach !!! but.. finally I have to travel around all node.. it isn't my intention :( I would like to decrease the number of searched node.